# Converting textures to mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing, 3d-printing

I am experimenting with the idea of converting a noise driven musgrave texture to a mesh. Form what I see musgrave 'blobs' change in 3D space, but applying to a mesh only applies the texture to the surface, naturally.
I have made a plane with a noise+musgrave driving a transparent shader and made an array of the plane to view/perceive the texture in 3D, sort of like a cat scan.
What I would like to do is to convert all the opaque parts to mesh surface and delete the transparent parts & then try and 'loft' between the 'lines' so as to get a solid amorphous contoured forms/surfaces and hopefully 3D print them out.
Is it even possible to do something like that in blender?
Any clues/hints would be great.
I am attaching a basic render for reference.
Thanks.[image]

Comment: I uploaded the blend file for reference here: https://ufile.io/g977lpmr

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that in Blender. The easiest way I can see accomplishing this would be to utilize a vector app like Illustrator. You could export the planes' textures from blender and then have the vector app trace the rasters. Then, you could export those as SVG/EPS and re-import into Blender and arrange the vector objects as needed.

Comment: If addressing to *"to convert all the opaque parts to mesh surface and delete the transparent parts"* then you can convert that drawing to svg via vector drawing app, import svg, set curve object to be beveled, then convert to mesh and clean it up. There're tutorials on the topic. Or you can "trace" that drawing in Blender with extruding a plane with the drawing as background image

Comment: @MrZak. can you please explain the 'trace' with extruding plane method? I'm not sure if I understand how to do that.
Thanks

Comment: @PJMDesign Thanks I'll try that out.

Comment: You can use curves like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ty3L2ALvugc or mesh extrusion like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwTfNmFpCs0 when he's creating the base profile in the beginning of the video

Comment: @MrZak,Thank you!